# Find all positive integers $n$ for which $(n-1)!+1$ is a power of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As the title says,

> Find all positive integers $n$ for which $(n-1)!+1$ is a power of $n$.

The solutions I've found are $\{2,3,5\}$ (*thanks Brandon!*), but I'm having difficulties proving that these are the only ones. What I've got so far is that $n$ must be prime since $(n-1)!+1$ would not be congruent to $n$ if $n$ were composite.

Comment: $n=2,3$ are solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for primes $p < 1290,$ those for which
$$  1 + (p-1)! \equiv 0 \pmod{p^2}$$
are the three $$\{    5, \; \;   13, \; \; 563 \}$$

As soon as $p \geq 7,$ we have $(p-1)! > p^3,$ so we need $  1 + (p-1)! \equiv 0 \pmod{p^3},$ and, in fact, $  1 + (p-1)! \equiv 0 \pmod{p^4}.$ Quite rare.

Comment: On the other hand, $(13-1)!+1=13^2 \times 2834329$

Comment: @J.M. yes, I factored these for $p \leq 61$ in gp-Pari, I don't see any chance for more solutions, which is what the large unpredictable prime factor with $p=13$ tells me. I  know $v_{563} (1 + 562!) \geq 2$ but not the exact value.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an old problem in [ML](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=3452). Note that, the equation doesn't hold for primes $>5$ which is in fact the [Liouvilles'theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=183998&ml=1)

Comment: What does "ML" mean? If it is not a standard or common abbreviation (and it appears so to me), then it may be better to write it out in full.

Comment: It's pretty famous though! MathLinks.